# Displaying a different error message depending on whether user's account is locked or they entered bad credentials

Tags: java, spring

On the login page of our Spring application, I would like to display a different error message to the user when their account is locked (ie they have entered the incorrect password 3 or more times), than when their login credentials are incorrect. At the moment, the application always gives the error message "Your login attempt was not successful, try again. Reason: Bad credentials" regardless of whether the credentials were wrong or the account is locked.

In my messages.properties file I have the following:

```
login.form.error=Your login attempt was not successful, try again. Reason: Bad credentials
login.form.locked=Your login attempts reached maximum number of trials. Please contact the administrator.
```

In login.jsp I have this code:

```
<c:if test="${error}">
    <h1 class="heading-medium error-summary-heading esifWebErrorSummaryHeadingColor">
       <spring:message code="login.form.error" />
    </h1>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${locked}">
    <h1 class="heading-medium error-summary-heading esifWebErrorSummaryHeadingColor">
       <spring:message code="login.form.locked" />
    </h1>
</c:if>
```

Then in LoginController.java I have the following code:

```
public class LoginController {

    @Value("${datamart.web.base.app}")
    private String datamartBaseURL;

    @Autowired
    LandingPageHandler landingPageHandler; 

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView renderDocumentAsPathVariable(
                @RequestParam(value="error", required=false) String error, 
                @RequestParam(value="locked", required=false) String locked,
                HttpServletRequest request, 
                HttpServletResponse response
    ) throws IOException, ServletException 
    {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null && !(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            /* The user is logged in :) */
            landingPageHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, auth);
        }

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("login");
        mv.addObject("error", error != null);
        mv.addObject("locked", locked != null);

        return mv;
    }
}
```

I have tested this by deliberately locking out my account (entering the incorrect password 3 times in a row), then entering the correct password on the 4th login attempt, but it still displays the "bad credentials" error message rather than the "Your login attempts reached maximum number of trials" message. Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: have you debugged and checked the values of error and locked? also: do you persist this state somewhere?

Comment: Seems like it would be better to store login attempts (and if they failed) in memory and perform a lookup, basing your decision to show the locked out message on that.

Comment: @Stultuske I have tried logging the values of the error and locked variables, and on all the login attempts (including the 4th attempt, when the account is locked but I then use the correct password), error is empty and locked is null.

Comment: locked is null, so there's your problem. did you try this in the same session?

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, it was all in the same session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is probably an in memory repository with a latest login attempts.
 I've used [CircularFifoQueue](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html) to maintain only a handful of last attempts in memory. However, this isn't really a secure practice. Displaying different messages enables enumeration attacks. See more details [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_User_Enumeration_and_Guessable_User_Account_(OWASP-AT-002))